# Google Dart Access Specific Map Value

Tags: java, javascript, dictionary, dart, json

I'm attempting to access a specific value out of a map.  I have previously tried obtaining the index of the value, but that never worked properly.  I want to be able to get each value out of the Map separately through a print statement.  Below I have been able to only print out all values when I want to print out the displayName values one at a time.  The _predefinedFilterList is a List.  Please let me know if you need more information.

```
  for (Map filterMap in _predefinedFilterList) {
        dropDownEl.children.add(new OptionElement(data: filterMap["displayName"]));
       print("Test: "+filterMap["displayName"]);
        //show only percentage of machines
//          dropDownEl.children[0].remove();
//          dropDownEl.children[1].remove();
 //         dropDownEl.children[1].hidden = true;
//          dropDownEl.children[2].remove();
 //       dropDownEl.children[5].remove();
      }
```

Comment: I find this question very confusing. Can you add a Map literal as an example of a map you are using and then give an example what you want to do with the map.

Comment: When you don't get an answer you should not ask the same question again but instead improve your original question.

Comment: Ok, how would I go about adding specific filterMap["displayName"] values?  Like filterMap["displayName"][1];?